# Convert Single line text to Multiline text (MS CRM 2016)

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

I would ask about capability to change the filed datatype from *Single line* to *Multiline* without delete this field.

Actually the CRM form editor is disable the data type option set after filed created, so I think I have to change the data type via Database

[image]

but I need to know if is it possible to do that, and if we change the data type from the database is it will change the filed from single line shape to multiline in the form.?
 because my CRM is online so I need confirm is it possible, to ask Microsoft to do it for me.

Best regards .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to convert a single line text field to a multi-line text field. Instead you should create a new multi-line text field and move the data from the old field to the new field.

If you were on-premise, you should not be making direct changes to the database (and there is no way Microsoft would be doing so for you online):

> [Modifying tables, stored procedures, or views in the database is not
>   supported.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328350.aspx#Anchor_4)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, as Henrik mentions, it's not possible, but tools can make it appear to be for all practical purposes ;)

The Attribute Manager (it's a plugin for the the [XrmToolBox](http://www.xrmtoolbox.com/)) will do this for you.  It's in beta, so don't run it in prod without testing it in another environment first.

Just select your field, check Convert Attribute Type (optionally check Migrate Data if you want it migrated) and execute.  You'll need to do it in each environment.

[image]

Comment: This should come with a **big warning** that it will create a new attribute presumably with the same name in each environment which will prevent transporting the entity via solution from one environment to the other.

Comment: This is what the "You'll need to do it in each environment" section is for.  Once you've done it in each environment (assuming Unmanaged Solutions), then there are not issues migrating solutions.

Comment: Did you try creating a attribute with the same name in 2 environments and transport the entity via unmanaged solution? You'll get an error on import stating that a field with this name already exists. Attributes get a unique identifier which will differ when creating them independently.

Comment: Pretty sure that's only managed @Filburt.  I've used the tool multiple times, with no issues in an unmanaged environments.

Comment: Trust me, I've seen this multiple times with some of our customers creating attributes in production and dev environments independently and the ensuing drama. The error message itself is even less helpful because it only tells you what you already know: There's an attribute with the same *name* - not that it throws a wobbly over the differing GUID.

Comment: Filburt, we'll have to agree to disagree.  I've been doing it in unmanaged environments for 4 years now.  As long as you run the tool in each environment, so the types are the same, and the attribute is unmanaged, CRM is OK with it