# How to change a field's type in CRM 2016

Tags: crm

We are running CRM 2016 SP1 on-premise. We have DEV, QA, Staging, and Production environments. The solution in our DEV, QA and Staging is unmanaged but in Production is managed.

We have a requirement to change some fields' data types from single line text to multiple line text in our production environment.

I have been researching this and have found the following links:

https://debajmecrm.com/2014/04/12/change-field-data-type-in-mscrm-without-dropping-and-recreating-the-field/

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/workandstudybook/archive/2014/07/28/converting-single-line-text-to-multi-line-text-using-crm-sdk-s-configuration-migration-tool

[Convert Single line text to Multiline text (MS CRM 2016)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41671517/convert-single-line-text-to-multiline-text-ms-crm-2016)

From what I understand from these pages, my options are as follows:

1. Change the field types directly in the database
2. Use tools such as Configuration Manager or Attribute Manager (XrmToolbox) to export data, delete the field, create new field, and import data back for the new field.

Option 1 requires making changing directly to the database which is something we rather not do as it will cause problems with Microsoft licensing.

Option 2 requires deleting the old field and creating a new field with the same name in EVERY environment. This means the new field will have the same name but different GUID values in every environment.

Am I right in assuming that option 2 will result in errors in the future when we want to deploy a solution from one environment to another because the GUIDs for the new field are different?

Also, Option 2 requires the solution to be unmanaged in all environments. However, in our case, it is managed in Production.
With all these in mind, what are my choices? What is the best way of achieving this?

Your comments are greatly appreciated.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to do this:

1. Hide the original field from forms, views, reports, etc.
2. Optional - Set the original field to be non-searchable (so it doesn't appear in advanced find).
3. Optional - Rename the original field so it's clear it shouldn't be used, someone people like to prefix with a 'z' so it appears at the bottom of lists.
4. Create your new field, put it in all the same places as the original.
5. Migrate the data from original to new field. A workflow executed in bulk could do, or perhaps an export, edit, import.
6. Optional - Delete the original field.

In terms of your options above; 1, that's unsupported (unlikely to mess your licencing, but has a good chance of ruining CRM with no way to sensible recover). 2, looks similar to my suggestion above.

Comment: A couple of questions: 1. Is this something you have done yourself? And any problems encountered if you have? 2. Excuse me if this sounds rather silly (because I am relatively new to CRM). with your solution, I assume I do not have to make the change, i.e. hide/delete the field manually, in every environment (because the new field has a new name not the same name as the old one). So am I right in assuming that once I have made the change and created and run a workflow to import the data into the new filed, I only need to import the solution to other environments?

Comment: 1. Yes, happens all the time, not a big deal. Biggest issue is probably amount of data to be updated, e.g. if you have millions of records. 2. Yes, transfer your changes in a solution, no need to do this manually.

Comment: Thanks a lot James. One last question: How about the multiple views that depend on the old field? How can I automatically update those views in one go so that they make use of the new field instead?

Comment: Fundamentally you have to update each one individually, there is a view replicator tool in the XrmToolbox which might help.